# filter contact names by sql query

Tags: android, sql, android-contacts

I have been trying to get all the contacts using the ContactsContract. I want to filter the results using the 'selection' parameter. In other words, I want to retrieve all the contacts that start with the letter A. So I wrote this snippet. But it crashes.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID, // the contact id column
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,  // column if this contact is deleted
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER   };

String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + 
            " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
cursor = getContentResolver().query
            (uri,
            projection,
            "android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME like 'A'",
            null,
            sortOrder);
```

As I know, I can insert into the selection parameter as what you can insert in where clause in SQL statements and that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
db.query(
  TABLE_NAME,
  projection, 
  Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like " + "'?%'",
  new String[] { "A" },
  null, null, null
);
```

Comment: There is only one null at the end. However I wrote cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
    projection,
    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like " + "'?%'",
      new String[] { "A" },
    sortOrder); and it crashes.

Comment: Yes I tried your query, The ? did not work with me. But it works in this way; getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like " + "'A%'", null, null).  Thanks